# Android app with xampp server

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have Android app that connect MySQL db on XAMPP server I tested it on different devices but a problem happened which is if the device on same network it will access PHP files that access db on my server but if it's on another network it can't access the PHP file 
in Android app I have access the server through 192.168.1.10\xxx.php which is static IP of my computer(server) where XAMPP on it

Answer (score 0):

The address space 192.168... is reserved for private intranets. If you are not inside of your private intranet meaning behind your router, then this IP directs you nowhere.

You have to get a public IP address.

Actually you already have one as soon as your router connects to the internet. You can find out which one with services like [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com). Then you have to change the settings of your router to redirect incoming requests to your hardware, which runs the XAMPP instance (in your case it's 192.168.1.10). You can check if this works by entering the IP you got from the service above into your browser address bar. You should be able to access your XAMPP instance. Please keep in mind, that from now on your personal PC is reachable over the internet, which can be a sever security issue.

If you've come that far, you have to replace the IP in your android app by the IP you found out with the service above. Then everything should work fine.

But this is just something to play with... as already mentioned it can be seriously dangerous to expose your PC to the public internet. Second your public IP is most likely to change on every reconnect of your browser, so that you have to replace the IP inside the app on a regular basis. You could use services like [dyndns.org](http://dyndns.org) to overcome this problem. Third ... well, ... just annoying to set this up.

I'd buy some cheap webspace and install the code you are running locally now there. You get a domain in most cases for free which automatically points to your public ip, and this domain name can be placed inside your android app.

Comment: thank you I think I'd buy webspace because my android app will be on different networks